# OS X - How to open any application from our application

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to open any application from my mac through my full screen application.

I have use following code to open application. Application opens behind my application.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"AppName"];
```

I have tried a lot.

Comment: 1. What's the `[NSWindow level]` of your app? 2. How did you get 3 upvotes in 1 minute for such a mundane question?

Comment: I dont know about upvotes.

Comment: How about the other question?

Comment: I am new in cocoa developement, I have used enterfullscreenmode for main screen.

Comment: That's nice, but we cannot help unless you give us some details.  Post the code that creates the app window.

Comment: I have used [[self window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[vC.view enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:nil];

Answer (score 2):

The issue is basically because using `[NSView enterFullScreenMode:withOption:]` will set the app's `[NSWindow level]` to `kCGMaximumWindowLevel - 1`, so that all other app's windows will appear behind it.

This is kinda what you would expect from a fullscreen app, which implies system-modal behaviour.

Comment: I am trying to cover whole the screen thats why i have used enter full screen mode.Can you tell me how can I cover whole screen with NSWindow

Comment: @Dhanashree No, I don't think you can do what you want to do.